# Always show hidden in Open/Save dialogs

Tags: macos, dialog

Is it possible to set by default to show hidden files and folders in Open and Save dialogs ?

I know it is possible to trigger to show hidden for dialog lifetime by press <kbd>Command ⌘</kbd>+<kbd>Shift ⇧</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd>.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just [asked](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/99213/23545) this question again, since there were no real answers here, and according to [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/99214/23545) all you need to do is run

```
defaults write -g AppleShowAllFiles -bool true
```

and restart whichever application(s) you're using, and you're all set. No restarting Finder or your computer. Brilliant!

Comment: This is not work.

Comment: It works on Mountain Lion 10.8.4, I don't know about other versions. You may also need to use `sudo` at the beginning of the command

Comment: Tried again, it works but not everywhere, it is depends on application.. in TextEdit for example not.

Answer (score 0):

Not without using the `chflags nohidden` command, which is not recommended.  One of the third-party file manager utilities such as [PathFinder](http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/6371/path-finder) may have such an option.

Comment: chflags nohidden work only for Finder, not Open/Save dialogs. Also I don't see how PathFinder can help.

Comment: chflags nohidden should affect file dialogs as well, but it can't be used to show files that start with a period.

Answer (score 0):

In the terminal enter

```
defaults write com.apple.Finder AppleShowAllFiles 1
```

Comment: This will work only when you browsing through Finder itself, my question is when you browsing through Save or Open dialogs in any other application.

Comment: @dimdeep MattDMo's answer worked for me