# Is it possible to always show hidden/dotfiles in Open/Save dialogs?

Tags: macos, settings

It is possible to show so-called dotfiles/directories like `.git` or files/directories that have the `Hidden` attribute in the Finder by running

```
defaults write com.apple.Finder AppleShowAllFiles 1
```

from the command line (then running `killall Finder` to restart it). However, this only works in Finder, not in applications' Open/Save dialogs. In those, one can use the <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>⇧</kbd><kbd>.</kbd> keyboard shortcut to show these files, but you have to use it **each time** you open a new dialog as the settings aren't saved.

Does anyone know of any kind of way to make this setting permanent? It could involve a Terminal command, editing a `.plist` or other file on an application by application basis, anything. [This question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/65419/23545) was asked a while ago with no satisfactory answers, so I'd like to see if there have been any changes in Mountain Lion, or if anyone knows an answer that just missed the first question. I'm currently running 10.8.4, if it makes any difference.

Comment: This is NOT a duplicate. This question is about Open/Save Dialogs. The other one ( https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/5870/how-to-show-hidden-files-and-folders-in-finder ) is about Finder. If you do the solution in the other one, it will fix for Finder, but not Open/Save Dialogs. You have to do the solution in this one.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

Just adding the key to the global domain seems to work:

```
defaults write -g AppleShowAllFiles -bool true
```

You have to quit and reopen applications to apply changes as usual.

Comment: Hooray! Thank you very much, I knew it had to be possible somehow. And I should also add that you don't need to restart Finder for it to work, unlike the original version. Thanks again!

Comment: This is not work. 10.8.4

Comment: @diimdeep What applications did you test it with? It doesn't work with some applications like TextMate that customize the file dialogs.

Comment: TextEdit, Sublime Text at least.

Comment: It works for me with TextEdit in 10.8.4. If there is a key in TextEdit's plist (`defaults read com.apple.TextEdit AppleShowAllFiles`) or `~/Library/Preferences/ByHost/.GlobalPreferences.*.plist` (`defaults -currentHost read -g AppleShowAllFiles`), they override the key in `~/Library/Preferences/.GlobalPreferences.plist`.

Comment: Is there a way to undo (defaults write -g AppleShowAllFiles -bool true)? I (probably foolishly) entered this in Terminal, and now I am getting strange files appearing on the desktop! :(

Comment: this strange files is just hidden system files, to turn off this option just 'defaults write -g AppleShowAllFiles -bool false'

Comment: The extra -g worked for me: and I did not even need to restart the affected app.

Comment: Global didn't work for me with 10.10.3 and Sublime Text 3083.

Comment: Works on Sierra macOS 10.12.2 with Sublime Text 3. Thanks!