# Hotkey to show hidden files and folders in File Open dialog?

Tags: macos

This question is very similar to [Is it possible to always show hidden/dotfiles in Open/Save dialogs?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/99213/83961). [How to show hidden files and folders in finder?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/5870/83961) is also related. However, I ***don't*** want to always show them, and that's what `defaults write ... AppleShowAllFiles ...` does.

Rather, I want to switch it on when needed. I'm trying to open `.bash_profile`, so I need it now:

[image]

Linux and Gnome allow us to <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> to toggle between showing and hiding hidden files. But Gnome hotkeys don't work on OS X (which is expected).

For completeness, `.bash_profile` does exist in the home directory:

```
$ ls ~/.bash_profile 
/Users/jww/.bash_profile
```

---

A related question... As can be seen above, typing the filename in Finder (or is it Spotlight) search did not work. I tried to right click to get a context menu in the File Open dialog in hopes of checking a box like "show all files". And I tried the View menu looking for a "show all files" with the File Open dialog open.

Why is this hidden away somewhere? What purpose does it serve to ***not*** allow a user to easily open a file?

Answer (score 524, accepted):

<kbd>⌘ CMD</kbd>+<kbd>⇧ SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd> reveals hidden files in Finder and Open/Save dialogs.

If you are using an AZERTY keyboard, you'll need to press <kbd>fn</kbd> too, so <kbd>⇧ SHIFT</kbd> is taken into consideration as you already need it to make the <kbd>.</kbd>.

---

You can also press <kbd>⌘ CMD</kbd>+<kbd>⇧ SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> and type the path to the hidden folder, just like in Terminal (<kbd>⇥ TAB</kbd> autocompletion also works).

Editing hidden files can be dangerous if you don't know what you're doing.

Comment: Works for me in Column view if I change path - go to another drive & back again, etc. - or change view, to icon & back.

Comment: The keyboard shortcut "cmd+shift+." seems to work on a broader scale in Finder in Sierra (not just the Open/Save dialogs), in several views as well.

Comment: Wow, can't believe there is a shortcut for this, how oddly specific. Thanks!

Comment: @Mateusz, Does cmdshiftG even works without a first cmdshiftdot?

Comment: @Pacerier sure, why not?

Comment: @MateuszSzlosek, Doesn't seem to work for me. cmdshiftG cannot select the hidden file, not unless I first do a cmdshiftdot. It works for you?

Comment: Ah I get what you mean. So Yes CMD+SHIFT+G won't select hidden file unless you reveal them using CMD+SHIFT+. But You can still navigate to hidden folders using CMD+SHIFT+G without revealing them. Good point!

Comment: Alas, it doesn't work in El Capitan.

Comment: I used to use `defaults` command to do it for years, and I didn't know about the shortcut. This is indeed the best answer for this question  

Comment: Doesn't work in Mojave. It just shows/hides the status bar.

Comment: @redbeam_ It is still working for me in Mojave [10.14.3 Beta (18D32a)] in Open/Save and in Finder. Hiding/Showing Status Bar is done with `⌘`+`/`.

Comment: I found out that it works in open/save dialogs, but not in Finder. The 'command' + 'slash' combination doesn't do anything. Could it be because of my keyboard layout being Slovak? My MacOS is the latest version by the way.

Comment: Doesnt work for me, I need to upload publish ssh key to AWS and cant select it in my .ssh directory

Answer (score 23):

Mateusz Szlosek covered the first part. Below is how I have handled the second part for my own use.

In my haste to post my answer, I did not realize the second part has already has been answered. See [How to set ⌘ + H to enable show hidden files](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/177132/how-to-set-%E2%8C%98-h-to-enable-show-hidden-files/177138#177138). What I offer below differs by a dialog informing you of the current status.

I created a service using the Automator application. When I want to toggle the viewing of hidden files, I select "Toggle Hidden Files" from the Finder services submenu as shown below. (Hint: Click image for a better view.)

[image]

This will cause either pop shown below to appear.

[image]

[image]

The steps to create the service are give below.

1. Open the Automator, select a new document of type Service.
2. Drag the action "Run Shell Script" to the workflow pane.
3. Edit the contains to appear as shown below. (Hint: Click image for a better view.)

   [image]

   The text for the script is repeated below.

   ```
   STATUS=`defaults read com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles 2>/dev/null`
   if [ "$STATUS" == TRUE ]; then
       STATUS=`osascript -e 'tell app "Finder" to display alert "Finder is showing hidden files." buttons {"Cancel", "Hide"}'`
   else
       STATUS=`osascript -e 'tell app "Finder" to display alert "Finder is not showing hidden files." buttons {"Cancel", "Show"}'`
   fi
   if [ "$STATUS" == "button returned:Show" ]; then
       defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles TRUE
       killall Finder
   elif [ "$STATUS" == "button returned:Hide" ]; then
       defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles FALSE
       killall Finder
   fi
   ```
4. Save (or move) the `Toggle Hidden Files.workflow` file to the
   `~/Library/Services` folder.
5. You may need to relaunch the Finder application in order for the
   service to appear on a menu.

### Update 1

Building off of Mateusz Szlosek's answer, I see the keyboard shortcut <kbd>⌘ CMD</kbd>+<kbd>⇧ SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd> could be added for my service. Go to System Preferences and click on the Keyboard icon. Select "Services" then "Toggle Hidden Files" under the "General" heading. Replace "none" with the <kbd>⌘ CMD</kbd>+<kbd>⇧ SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd> keyboard short cut.

Comment: I did exactly as you've told (there is said file in my ~/Library/Services folder), but to no avail even after restarting the computer.

Comment: @Walter: I have added the `Toggle Hidden Files.workflow` to Sourceforge.net. See the site: [Toggle Hidden Files](https://sourceforge.net/projects/toggle-hidden-files/files/?source=navbar). You can download the workflow from there. The instructions for installation are also show at this site.

Comment: Why change the built-in key shortcut, which works in File dialogs, to a Service, which doesn't, and which quits the Finder? (Quitting the Finder can cause the foreground Finder window to close.)

Answer (score 3):

**DISCLAIMER/WARNING**

Hidden files are hidden for a reason usually. Use the script below only if you're reasonably sure you know what you're doing. In other words: If you break your system by randomly deleting hidden files, it's your own fault.

---

Here's the script I use to toggle show/don't show hidden files inside **Finder**.

(The OSX native shortcut to toggle hidden files in **Open/Save dialogues** was mentioned by Mateusz Szlosek above already)

The difference between my script and others I've seen so far:

Most scripts don't do anything else after killing Finder. Usually, this means you have to navigate back to the folder you were in originally, since the automatic Finder relaunch doesn't reliably open your last active folder.

**The script below instead reopens, and focuses on, your last active folder, i.e. the folder you were in when using the toggle, but now showing (or not showing) hidden files.**

I assigned a shortcut to it (cmd+shift+.) and find working with hidden files in Finder a lot more convenient now.

Credit to Tetsujin who posted a script on this site a while ago that I adapted to add the 'reopen last folder' functionality.

```
on run {input, parameters}
    tell application "Finder"
        set var1 to POSIX path of (target of window 1 as alias)
    end tell
    set newHiddenVisiblesState to "YES"
    set oldHiddenVisiblesState to do shell script "defaults read com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles"
    if oldHiddenVisiblesState is in {"1", "YES"} then
        set newHiddenVisiblesState to "NO"
    end if
    do shell script "defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles " & newHiddenVisiblesState
    ---- Sleep hack mentioned below. 0.5s minimum, 1-2s safer. Ugly, but (probably) unavoidable.
    do shell script "killall Finder; sleep 0.5s"
    tell application "Finder"
        ---- Close other windows if Finder managed to relaunch already
        if application "Finder" is running then
            close every window
        end if
        open (var1 as POSIX file)
        activate
    end tell
end run
```

To use the script: Open a new workflow in Automator, drag in "Run AppleScript", copy&paste the code above, and save inside your services folder (usually, ~/Library/Services/, afaik).

Attaching a shortcut to execute a script should be covered somewhere else on this site. I limited the scope of my shortcut to Finder alone.

---

Style remark:

I have to resort to a bit of an ugly hack, using 'sleep' after killing Finder, before manually opening the original folder.

If I don't force this delay, there's a chance OSX relaunched Finder already and opened a folder (not necessarily the last active one, in my experience). Together with my own 'open' command, this can lead to the nasty effect of two (unkillable, even) Finder processes running, and Finder not working anymore at all. If this happens, logging out and back in again fixes it, but it's a waste of time obviously, so I use 'sleep'.

A sleep value of 0.5s works for me, but to be on the safe side, you can slightly increase it (adding a more noticeable delay to the process then).

If someone knows of a way to either suppress the Finder relaunch and unreliable opening of some window after sending the killall signal -- or some other way to get rid of the 'sleep' hack -- I'd be happy to hear it!