# Show hidden all files, but hide some

Tags: macos, finder

I am trying to show all files and hide some. I know about the command:

```
defaults write com.apple.Finder AppleShowAllFiles -bool YES
```

But that shows even files that I have hidden with `chflags hidden`. I want to hide those files. Is it possible to change its name into a ._ file, or is that not safe? I don't want to `chflags nohidden` manually one by one. Is there a way to do so?

---

Mac OS X 10.9.5 (Mavericks)

Comment: Which file names to you want to change to `.filename`?

Comment: For example, applications, text files. If possible, even folders. Like maybe change "secret.txt" to "._secret.txt" and open it through terminal. with showallfiles set to YES, i can see .filename files. However not ._filename Is it safe to do ._? I might need to unhide it as well

Comment: You can name your own files however you want to (well, mostly at least). Renaming files provided or required by the OS and/or applications will break things though

Comment: @patrix so it is unsafe to hide files by putting ._ before them? If yes, is there another way to hide files even from AppleShowAllFiles

Comment: It's unsafe to rename system- or application-provided files in any way (e.g. if you rename your `Library` folder to `._Library`, you better have a second account configured or know how to use single user mode if you want to log in again).

Comment: Basically not worth the risk. As David Anderson said, future updates could mess it up as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `.filename` was intended by unix to represent invisible file names. Even before there was GUI's, the `ls` command by default would not list these files for normal users. There is no reason you can not add a `.` prefix to your own file names.

On the other hand, using `._filename` seems to be unique to OS X. One use of these filenames is to store addition information regarding files with the same name minus the `._` prefix. OS X even has a special command `dot_clean` to delete or merge these types of files.

In my option, I would not risk deliberately using the `._` prefix in my filenames. You may get acceptable results now, but future versions of OS X may interpret such names differently.

For example, let's say you create a file called `._dave`. Later could OS X end up creating a file called `._._dave`?

Just FYI:
It is possible to create a service that would allow you to set the hidden file flag for highlighted files using the Finder application. The instructions are given below.

1. Open the Automator application.
2. From the menu bar choose "File", then "New".
3. Select "Service" and click "Choose".
4. Drag the action "Run AppleScript" to where it says "Drag actions or
   files here to build your workflow".
5. Set "Service receives selected `text` in `any application`" to
   "Service receives selected `files or folders` in `Finder`".
6. Replace the code

   ```
   on run {input, parameters}

       (* Your script goes here *)

       return input
   end run
   ```

   with

   ```
   on run {input, parameters}
       try
           repeat with currentfile in input
               try
                   do shell script "chflags hidden " & quoted form of POSIX path of currentfile
               end try
           end repeat
       end try
       return input
   end run
   ```
7. Save service as "Set Hidden Flag".
8. Close all Automator windows and quit the Automator application.

The service should have been saved in the `~/Library/Services` folder under the name `Set Hidden Flag.workflow`. If not, move it there.

Now when you highlight one or more files using the Finder application, you can right click and select "Set Hidden Flag" to hide from the Finder application.

A simular service named "Reset Hidden Flag" can be created using the same steps, with the following two exceptions. In step 6, change

```
do shell script "chflags hidden " & quoted form of POSIX path of current file
```

to

```
do shell script "chflags nohidden " & quoted form of POSIX path of current file
```

In step 7, change to save as "Reset Hidden Files".

Of course, you can not highlight the hidden files unless the Finder application displays them. To do this see my answer to [Hotkey to show hidden files and folders in File Open dialog?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/186376/hotkey-to-show-hidden-files-and-folders-in-file-open-dialog/186388#186388)

Comment: Also using zip tools or other copies to and from non HFS disks will merge undergo the ._ files

Comment: Thanks. The solution then is to make a service that hides them. And `sudo ls` shows hidden files as well?

Comment: @Mark: I was thinking if someone executed `dot_clean -n` is an effort to clean their folders. This command deletes each dot underbar file if there is no matching native file. All of TheBro21's files would be gone.

Comment: Yes I was just adding other cases where he would lose files

Comment: @TheBro21 The solution is not to do that you will corrupt data using ._ files

Comment: @TheBro21: Use `ls -A` or `ls -a` instead of `sudo ls`. This will save you from having to type a password. Also, I updated my answer.