# no such file or directory when starting terminal

Tags: terminal, zsh, path

I'm not a power user and  recently installed Homebrew and Powershell on my MacBook running Ventura 13.1 to control my new T-Mobile Home Internet Gateway and since I get the following when running terminal:

`/Users/ron/.zshrc:3: no such file or directory: /usr/local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/System/Cryptexes/App/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin# ➜  ~`

Any help would be appreciated.

BTW: Powershell is working great.

```
➜  ~ cat ~/.zshrc

# Add Homebrew's executable directory to the front of the PATH
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH# If you come from bash you might have to change your 
$PATH.
export PATH=$HOME/bin:/usr/local/bin:$PATH
    
# Path to your oh-my-zsh installation.
export ZSH="/Users/ron/.oh-my-zsh"
```

Comment: What is in your ~/.zshrc

Comment: if I type ~/.zshrc – mmmmmm    I get sh: permission denied: /Users/ron/.zshrc
zsh: command not found: mmmmmm

Comment: I meant what is in your ~/.zshrc ie output of `cat ~/.zshrc`

Comment: I tried to paste the output of that command but got the following: Too long by 3229 characters

Comment: I added the output of cat ~/.zshrc – 
mmmmmm
here: https://docs.google.com/document/d/12FXAtMxfgJAryuZP-8Rl-vXzHdMO1q63536wEU4Mf6s/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Just add the first 6 lines to the question

Comment: ➜  ~ cat ~/.zshrc – 
mmmmmm

# Add Homebrew's executable directory to the front of the PATH
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH# If you come from bash you might have to change your 
$PATH.
export PATH=$HOME/bin:/usr/local/bin:$PATH

# Path to your oh-my-zsh installation.
export ZSH="/Users/ron/.oh-my-zsh"

Comment: Put that in the question and not in the comment especially as we need to see exactly how it is formatted

Comment: To clarify one thing: "mmmmmm" is the username of the person who has been responding to you, it is not text that you should be including in your shell commands.

Comment: Thanks for that clarification, I've added those lines above.

Comment: You have an error message, you know the exact place where the error occurs, so what's the problem then?  While you have posted part of your .zshrc, it is not entirely clear to me which is line 3. I would use a text editor to exactly see what line 3 is. If the answer by mmmmmm solves your case, please accept it (by clicking on the checkmark next to the answer).

Comment: I did not realize I needed to check off to accept the answer that solved the issue. Done

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My view on shell startup files is do not put anything in them that you do not understand so that you can debug them when they go wrong.

The issue here is that you have copied the file from somewhere and it has altered line endings. Probably by using an editor that wraps lines to a fixed side or that the original web site did not expand the text enough.

Your error is as the error says in line 3.

From the google doc (assuming that has not wrapped lines - please use plain text editors not word processors for scripts) line 3 is just

```
$PATH
```

This expands to the path and is not an executable. In this case it should be at the end on line 2 which is ended with a comment  or more likely the comment should be line 3 including the $PATH as I think the comment refers to the next line.

My guess of the correct file

```shell
# Add Homebrew's executable directory to the front of the PATH
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
# If you come from bash you might have to change your $PATH.
export PATH=$HOME/bin:/usr/local/bin:$PATH

# Path to your oh-my-zsh installation.
export ZSH="/Users/ron/.oh-my-zsh"
```

The 4th line which should be line 3 is the only one that does the change for Homebrew.

The rest is setup on-my-zsh and then the rest is comments so I would delete all that.

Comment: I give that a go once I figure how to make the edit.

Comment: See https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/192658/237 but ~/.zshrc instead of ~/.bash_profile

Comment: Thanks for all your help and guidance, I edited the file , tested and the error message is gone and powershell still works.  I'm happy and greatfull to you mmmmmm and I'm sure glad I found this forum.