# Mac terminal can't be used after set up of ~/.bash_profile

Tags: macos, terminal

I was installing Apache Ant earlier and once I did, I also ran:

```
touch ~/.bash_profile
nano .bash_profile
```

Within that text file I wrote:

```
. .bash_profile
```

saved, exited, then ran:

```
source ~/.bash_profile
```

Now my Terminal looks like this:

[image]

I can't access my command line at all, so I went into preferences and set

```
/bin/bash -x
```

to run as a default upon Terminal's open, and now it looks like this:

[image]

and still reads

```
[Process Completed]
```

afterward. Any help?

Answer (score 7):

You've got a recursive inclusion in your `.bash_profile`.

You can always edit the file in `TextEdit.app` (or another graphical text editor of your liking) if you get in to deep trouble like this.

Open up `TextEdit` using Spotlight or via Finder and then type <kbd>⌘ CMD</kbd>+<kbd>o</kbd> to get the `Open File...` dialog. Press <kbd>⌘ CMD</kbd>+<kbd>⇧ SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd> to [reveal hidden files in the dialog box](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/186378/292) and then find your `~/.bash_profile` file. Remove the:

```
. .bash_profile
```

from the file and save it and you'll have a working `bash` shell again.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way to get to a shell without running startup commands is to use Terminal’s

> **Shell > New Command…**

to run `bash --noprofile`. This tells Bash not to run the login startup script. Other shells have similar options, e.g., `zsh --no_rcs`.

This avoids changing preferences and only affects a specific terminal, which you can then use to edit startup scripts or other configuration files that are causing problems.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it using:

```
/bin/zsh
```

as the default command upon open(with 'run in shell' unchecked). 
Then:

```
rm ~/.bash_profile
```

Then change default command upon open back to:

```
/bin/bash
```

Comment: You can also edit the file directly with an editor like Sublime, if you can't initiate a shell.

Answer (score 0):

Your `.bash_profile` is called automatically as your terminal loads. The `.` command is the same as `source`, it calls the shell script and loads it into the environment of the calling shell (as opposed to a child shell).

So what you have here is the bash profile script being called recursively. You can open it another text editor and remove the offending `. .bash_profile`. There are several technique to seeing or opening hidden files from Finder.

If the script is on a remote box, then you will need to find another shell to edit the profile script.