# Changing the Finder icon for an external disk formatted as ExFat?

Tags: macos, finder, external-disk, icon

I used this web page recipe - [Create Your Own Custom Icons in OS X 10.7.5 or Later](http://blog.macsales.com/28492-create-your-own-custom-icons-in-10-7-5-or-later) - for creating a `.icns` icon set containing a set of icons for an external disk that has been formatted with the ExFat file system.

However, whatever I do, when I drag the `.icns` file on top of the drive, it just shows a .png dummy icon:

[image: Drive icon for ExFat file system]

If I erase the drive and reformat it as OS X Journaled, then repeat the process, the icon is shown correctly:

[image: drive icon for OS X Journaled file system]

Is there a trick where I can reassign the icon also for an ExFat drive? I plan on using this drive both on a Windows machine and on my MacBook so keeping it as OS X Journaled isn't really an option. I know there are custom software for Windows so that I can read and write OS X file system disks but that's not an option either since I plan on connecting this drive to computers where I cannot really expect the owner to install custom software to use the disk.

And the icon is not *that* important. It would just be a nice touch.

What I've tried:

- Basic `.png` file (that works on OS X Journaled formatted drive)
- Full `.icns` file (that works on OS X Journaled formatted drive)

So can it be done? If so, how?

This is OS X El Capitan 10.11.4 and the drive is a [WD My Passport Air 1TB](http://www.wdc.com/en/products/products.aspx?id=1040) if if matters.

Comment: You can open a .png in Preview, select all and copy it, then click on the drive icon and paste. Does that work?

Comment: I am not sure what you are doing wrong. I tested on my Mac and this works.   My procedure is a little different from what you are using.

Comment: @IronCraftMan No, gives me the same incorrect image.

Comment: @DavidAnderson You did this with an ExFat drive?

Comment: Both fat and exfat. The test drive is a USB 4GB flash drive. MBR partitioned with 5 partitions. I don't think GPT partitioning would be different. How is your drive partitioned?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do a "Get Info" on the drive. This brings up the info window. To add the icon, I drag and drop the `.icns` file on the image shown in the upper left corner of the window.

> When I refer to a "drive", what I really mean is a partition located on a physical or virtual drive. Since the partition is ExFAT formatted, the partition can also be referred to as a volume.

Maybe your `.icns` file is no good. Maybe you should try one of mine. You can download the ones I use [here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/mac-icns/). Or, you can try the free online tool I used to create these `.icns` files. Go to [iconvert icons](https://iconverticons.com/online/).

When you drop the `.icns` file, a copy of this file is renamed `.VolumeIcon.icns` and placed in the root directory of the drive. For example, if I use a Terminal application window, I can show this file.

```
Steelhead:~ davidanderson$ diskutil list /dev/disk1
/dev/disk1 (external, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:     FDisk_partition_scheme                        *4.0 GB     disk1
   1:             Windows_FAT_32 UNTITLED 1              808.2 MB   disk1s1
   2:                 DOS_FAT_32 UNTITLED 2              808.2 MB   disk1s2
   3:               Windows_NTFS UNTITLED 3              808.2 MB   disk1s3
   4:                 DOS_FAT_32 UNTITLED 4              808.2 MB   disk1s5
   5:                 DOS_FAT_32 UNTITLED 5              808.1 MB   disk1s6
Steelhead:~ davidanderson$ mount | grep disk1
/dev/disk1s1 on /Volumes/UNTITLED 1 (msdos, local, nodev, nosuid, noowners)
/dev/disk1s2 on /Volumes/UNTITLED 2 (msdos, local, nodev, nosuid, noowners)
/dev/disk1s3 on /Volumes/UNTITLED 3 (exfat, local, nodev, nosuid, noowners)
/dev/disk1s5 on /Volumes/UNTITLED 4 (msdos, local, nodev, nosuid, noowners)
/dev/disk1s6 on /Volumes/UNTITLED 5 (msdos, local, nodev, nosuid, noowners)
Steelhead:~ davidanderson$ cd "/Volumes/UNTITLED 3"
Steelhead:UNTITLED 3 davidanderson$ ls -l .VolumeIcon.icns
-rwxrwxrwx@ 1 davidanderson  staff  26582 May  5 15:50 .VolumeIcon.icns
Steelhead:UNTITLED 3 davidanderson$
```

Here is a screen shot from my Desktop.

[image]

### If you something goes wrong read this:

There must be a cache of volume names to icons buried in OS X. I say this because no matter what combination of reformats, ejects, unmounts and deletes I preform, the same icon reappears. Something like the following is happening:

1. The  operating system encounters a valid `.VolumeIcon.icns` file in
   the root directory of a partition (volume).
2. The `.VolumeIcon.icns` is read in to the cache and associated with
   the volume name.
3. Even if the `.VolumeIcon.icns` file is changed, the operating system
   does not update the cache. (This is *one* of the bugs!)

If you do the following, you may have a shot at success. I do not guarantee this to be an inclusive list.

1. Remove the `.VolumeIcon.icns` (if it exists) from the root folder on
   the drive, by following these instructions.  Highlight the drive
   (volume) and select "Get Info" from the menu bar. Next, highlight
   the icon shown in the upper left of the pop up window. Finally,
   from the menu bar, select "Cut". Note: This file is not normally
   shown in the Finder, unless you enable the Finder to [Show Hidden
   Files](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/186376/hotkey-to-show-hidden-files-and-folders-in-file-open-dialog/186388#186388).
2. Rename the drive to some name never used before.
3. Eject the drive and remove from the computer.
4. If necessary, quit the Disk Utility application.
5. If necessary, quit the Terminal application.
6. Close all Finder Windows"
7. Hold down the <kbd>option</kbd> key and right click on the Finder
   icon on the Dock. Select "Relaunch".
8. Connect the drive back into the computer
9. Drag and drop the `.icns` files on the icon in the upper left corner
   of the "Get Info" window for the drive. **It may appear as if
   nothing has happened.**
10. (Optional) Verify the `.VolumeIcon.icns` appears in the root folder 
    of the partition (volume). This file is not normally shown in the 
    Finder unless you enable the Finder to [Show Hidden Files](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/186376/hotkey-to-show-hidden-files-and-folders-in-file-open-dialog/186388#186388).
    Experienced users can also use the Terminal application to verify
    this file exists
11. Use the Disk Utility application to unmount the partition (volume).
12. Use the Disk Utility application to mount the partition (volume).

Comment: I tried with the first icon in that `.dmg` file, the "arrow_left.icns" file, and it shows as that odd `.png` icon for the ExFat drive, but shows properly for the OS X Journaled drive. The drive is partitioned as a Guid Partition Map.

Comment: @Lasse: If my update does not work, I give up! Be sure to read my answer all the way to the end.

Comment: I will try your final steps when I come back home later today, out of the house right now so don't have the disk. I did relaunch Finder and restart my computer at some point but I'm not sure what else I did just before and after so I'll be sure to try your specific steps. Thanks for the effort, even if it turns out not to help me out!

Answer (score 0):

Change the name of the drive will fix it

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different and thank you for your answer. :) Unfortunately, short answers such as this don't really provide enough detail or context to help many users. If possible, it'd be good if you could add some more info on why changing the drive's name will fix this? Do you know this from personal experience, or do you have another reference? Also, you may want to read [How to Answer](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-answer) for tips on providing answers here.

Comment: Actually, the answer seems correct. I have the same issue (macOS 12.5), an exFat disk that refuses to show the image I put in the Info. The moment I change the disk name the image shows correctly. However, the moment I change it back to the original name the previous image shows.