# Is there a keyboard shortcut for "Show Hidden Files" in the Finder in El Cap?

Tags: keyboard, finder, macos, shortcut

Related: [Hotkey to show hidden files and folders in File Open dialog?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/186376/hotkey-to-show-hidden-files-and-folders-in-file-open-dialog)

Looks like there was a keyboard shortcut for it. But in `10.11.6` all I get when I press `Cmd Shift .` is the bonk sound.

Is that keyboard shortcut gone? What's an easy way to get it back?

Note that the shortcut works in file dialogs but not the standard Finder window.

**Not a duplicate**: the top ranked question on [Hotkey to show hidden files and folders in File Open dialog?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/186376/hotkey-to-show-hidden-files-and-folders-in-file-open-dialog) does not work in El Cap.

Comment: I just realised I've already posted the solution to this... at least twice ;)

Comment: Yeah but those questions weren't specific to El Cap, so having it in a separate question will help. Thanks for posting again.

Comment: @jcollum I see you've edited this question with a comment re the duplicate. Are you saying that none of the answers in either the *duplicate* or *related* questions work in El Capitan?

Comment: That's right. The keyboard shortcut used to be there. Now it's gone. Marking it as a duplicate might make someone think that those questions answer _this specific question_, which they do not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no shortcut.
You could make one, but it would require a Automator action, containing a script, and set up as a Service, & will re-launch the Finder each time it's used. [Mavericks could do it without relaunch but no other OS]

For the number of times I actually use it, I just keep the script accessible instead.

```
--Toggle Invisibles
set newHiddenVisiblesState to "YES"
try
    set oldHiddenVisiblesState to do shell script "defaults read com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles"
    if oldHiddenVisiblesState is in {"1", "YES"} then
        set newHiddenVisiblesState to "NO"
    end if
end try
do shell script "defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles " & newHiddenVisiblesState & "; killall Finder"
```

Copy paste to Script Editor & save as an App.
It will toggle visible state each time it's launched.