# How can I show hidden files on 'choose a file' dialog in 3rd-party apps?

Tags: macos, filesystem

I want to choose a file under hidden directories on any application but Finder, but it seems to be not shown. For example, if I put a file called `my.terminal` under `~/Dropbox/.hidden/`, and try to choose the file on Terminal (`Preferences` -> `Profiles` -> `Import`), I could not reach the file because it is, I think, put under a hidden directory. The file is not searchable on the search box.

In this case, I first have to copy the file to other directories that are non-visible, and then choose the file again. This is quite painstaking and I want to avoid it, but is this possible on macOS (Big Sur)?

I already set the Finder such that it shows hidden files, but this has no effect on other applications.

Comment: Does ["Hotkey to show hidden files and folders in File Open dialog?"](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/186376/hotkey-to-show-hidden-files-and-folders-in-file-open-dialog) answer your question?

Comment: @GordonDavisson Hmmm partially. I was able to show the hidden files with command+shift+. or go to a directory with (command+shift+g) on 3rd-party applications  and find the file I want, but the search does not get me the file I want.

Comment: Spotlight will not index hidden or system files, even if you have them visible, so the first part can be done, but not the second.

Comment: @Tetsujin I see. Could you then write it in an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted, you have found how to show invisibles, in Finder and in file-picker dialogs…

You are going to be hampered, however, by the fact that Spotlight will not index hidden or System locations, so they will not show up in search.

A potential partial workaround would be to open your destination folder in Finder before you need it in an app. Then, when you are presented with any file-picker dialog, you can drag that folder into the dialog & the file-picker will go to that location.